# How to write a junit test to check that a json file is written correctly

Tags: java, json, junit, jackson

I need to write a unit test for a function that reads in a yaml of inputs and writes out a json file of results, but am finding that the function is unable to write to the file when called from junit. I know my function is working correctly outside of junit tests.

I have narrowed down the problem to the fact that the file is not being written at all. My function looks something like this, and uses Jackson to write to a json file:

`

```
public void computeFunction(Object input, String pathToOutput) {
  doSomething(input);
  String outputFile = pathToOutput + "/x1.json";
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  mapper.writeValue(new File(outputFile), x1);
}
```

`

And my test currently looks something like this.

```
@Rule
public TemporaryFolder folder = new TemporaryFolder()
@Test
public void TestFunction() throws Exception {
  File pathToOutput = folder.newFolder("results");
  String x1 = "input";
  Object input = new Object(x1)
  computeFunction(input, pathToOutput.getAbsolutePath());
  ObjectMapper mapper = newObjectMapper();
  List<Object> output = mapper.readValue(new File(pathToOutput + "x1.json"), new TypeReference<List<Object>>(){});
  assertEquals(val1, output.getValOne());
  assertEquals(val2, output.getValTwo());
}
```

Why isn't computeFunction able to write to the file during the junit test?

Edit --

I am getting an error at the line

```
List<Object> output = mapper.readValue(new File(pathToOutput + "x1.json"), new TypeReference<List<Object>>(){});
```

exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/junitxxxxx/results/x1.json
```

Comment: What does `isn't computeFunction able to write to the file` really mean? Please add error messages, logs, etc. which provided during tests.

Comment: “Design for testability.” For testability I would factor out a method for generating the JSON and returning it as a string from the method that you have. Testing JSON generation should not be bad, for example by parsing back. Writing to a file usually works, so I would be comfortable deferring that test to the integration test.

Comment: My guess is that the problem is here: `new File(pathToOutput + "x1.json")`. Try `new File(pathToOutput, "x1.json")`

Comment: @1615903 You are right, this was a mistake on stackexchange. I am passing the path to the function as a string.

Comment: @OleV.V. The main goal of this test is to verify the results of the computations, not check that the json file has been generated properly. computeFunction is intentionally void; Can you explain how I would parse that back, or how that would help me verify the results? The functions seems to be having trouble creating and writing to the file in the first place.

Comment: Did you understand the concept of a unit test the way I did? It’s a test of the smallest units of your code (hence the name). I would definitely test the results of computations *before* encoding/serializing them into JSON.